# How to loop through a product list and create jsonContent from a SchemaWorker on code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are implementing schema.org into our eCommerce homepage. I have to grab the list of items that are displayed on our homepage and get the position of these items and also the url from these items. Then I have to create jsonContent from them and pass it to the front end.

I have the schemaworker setup already I just need help on how I would loop through each item and grab the details needed.

```
int collid = Product.GetCollectionID(siteid, "Home Page");
List<Product> list = Product.ProductCollList(collid, siteid);
listProducts.DataSource = list;
listProducts.DataBind();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
StringBuilder sbItemListSchema = new StringBuilder();
string jsonConent = SchemaWorker.GetHomePageSchema()
}


ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), sbItemListSchema.ToString(), false);
```